# Telegram account needs to be confirmed every time when using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have some troubles with my client app in telegram. When I run my code, I have to confirm my account everytime (in the telegram itself, I need to enter the phone number and the code that came to the mail). The most interesting moment, that my code doesn't contain anything criminal. Just for testing

```
import asyncio
import configparser

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
username = config['Telegram']['username']

client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

client.start()

async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Month ago, everything was working fine. Then I was doing a small chat scraper for checking swear words. I would like to know, why such a problem has appeared now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue as you, when using telethon, my Telegram account would log out everywhere for no reason, even when I wasn't even doing anything in my code except starting client. Everything would work perfectly for ~30 seconds. It wouldn't ask me to log in again within that timeframe, but then it just disconnected all my sessions. Not only that, if I relogged with my mobile app too soon, it would disconnect me after ~30 seconds again. I've tried everything, but it seems to be some account-specific issue, because after I switched to a brand new account everything works as supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script is not terminating abruptly. If it is, the library won't have a chance to properly save the information. I would also recommend checking the active sessions from a different client, to learn whether Telethon's session is somehow "disappearing" on its own. And lastly, `logging.DEBUG` logs may have some hints.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue, plus it logs me out of all my sessions on all devices. This is most likely an update on Telegram's side. Moreover, telethon might have received an update.
I read somewhere that you need to pass a parameter to TelegramClient called system_version, where you have to pass in the version of your device. Apparently you can get it in debug mode in TG by sending a message. It should output an array of information like this:

```
api_id: [INT],
device_model: [STRING],
system_version:  [STRING],
app_version: [STRING],
system_lang_code: [STRING],
lang_pack: [STRING],
lang_code: [STRING],
```

Apparently all these parameters exist in TelegramClient(). I suppose system version is the most important in this case. I read a discussion on that here: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4051

Someone simply passed in `system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM"` and it worked.

Passing in system_version variable does work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to connect to the session without crashing. Telegram kicks you out because your device model and system version are missing, probably to fight spam

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash, device_model="iPhone 12 Pro", system_version="4.16.30-CUSTOM")
```

`client.start(89999999999)`